# How can I remove a binary from the XCode 6 App Submission menu?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6

I'm trying to submit my app for beta testing purposes (I would prefer to go the iTunes Connect distribution route). However it fails while trying to validate the .o file shown below. I would like to remove it from this list below.

I remember accidentally dragging that file outside the project in the project navigator.

Thanks.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: having the same problem here. seemingly random classes from the target's code appear as ".o" files and it won't allow sending the binary to the app store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your target's build phases. In copy bundle resources, you might have some code files that shouldn't be there. Removing them fixed the issue for me.